# 12.10 blue screen, desktop bars do not load

Tags: 12.10

just upgraded to Ubuntu 12.10. I can't reach the desktop, it is stuck on the blue screen, the desktop environnement does not load.
Only gnome with no effects works.

Can you help please?

config: thinkpad T400, 6 GB of Ram, graphic card: Intel Gma 4500Mhd

```
lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
```

I am not sure I have not messed up lightdm / gdm previously...

edit: I just tried a 12.10 live usb version and it works fine....so it is a problem in my install for sure.

Comment: maybe I did not understand your problem correctly ...
You could not see the login screen ? Or you could see the login screen, but, after logging in, you got a blue screen ?

Comment: indeed, I can login, and after the login screen I only see the desktop and no bars at all

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem after upgrading. You can follow what I did. 
Check the `~/.xsession-error` logs. If you have errors similar to this: 
`(update-notifier:2286): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-assets.css:494:61: Unrecognised image file format`
, then reinstall `libgdk-pixbuf2` and type the following as root user

`gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders --update-cache` and then reboot. If that does not suffice, install `gdk-pixbuf2.0-dev` and run the above command again. Reboot to see the changes. Hope your problem is resolved.

Answer (score 2):

i would also try  to reinstall ubuntu desktop with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` and execute this command `sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg` at console wich you can summon by pressing `cntrl alt f1` then just login with username and password and run the commands

Comment: Thanks @user85872 I  did that and now I see the desktop files but no top and side bars... and also I see a compiz error message...it quit unexpectedly.

Comment: you should try: sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity or summon the terminal by pressing cntrl+alt+t and type: ccsm if compiz settings manager not installed yet follow instructions there is sugested command in terminal to install it.After install is finished search for ubuntu 'unity plugin' in ccsm and see if it checked as enabled in options

Comment: I installed compiz manager. Unity plugin is activated. Still no bars on the desktop.  Same when reinstalling unity. It is weird because when I logout I see the top bar with clock, network, etc...

Comment: last advice i can give you is to reset unity to default settings by executing this in terminal copy: setsid unity . This is similar to unity --reset command in 12.04 lts wich now doesnt work in 12.10 then try
 to reset compiz: setsid compiz --replace
and restart X Display: Manager: 
sudo -s
setsid service lightdm restart and finaly try: unity --replace

Comment: When resetting compiz and unity I get a error: libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast. And it is the same for the other commands you mention.

Comment: I just installed gnome-shell trhough `sudo apt-get install gnome-shell`, then I rebooted and login with gnoem classic (no effects), and I get the desktop and the bar fine. So the problem seems to be just caused to the shell.

Comment: what should I do to have gnome3 or unity working fine?

Comment: let me think something is telling me it will be gnome 3.6 also i red it works faster then unity interface..

Answer (score 0):

just to check if you indeed messed up the lightdm:

1) go to a tty (i.e., press ctrl alt f1)
2) log in
3) run `xinit -- :1` (note the spaces! it is, indeed "--(a space):(no space)1")

this might open you a barebones X session (*) Then, at least, you'll know X is working

(*) just a white terminal in a black background.

---

If it is the case, the simple and ugly solution will be to use another login manager. After that, we can start investigating =P

install some new login managers:

```
sudo apt-get install xdm lxdm kdm
```

choose a login manager:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

then reboot so that your login manager has a chance to appear

Comment: thanks @josinalvo, with xinit -- :1 in tty1 I get a black background screen with a with a white terminal (like Xterm)...but I cannot move it eround the screen or anything else... is X working then?

Comment: yep. X is working

Comment: ok thank you. Simple effective test. I did what you suggested. I can login but none of the dm (i tried  gdm lightdm kdm xdm ) leads to the displaying of the desktop... what should I do now ;-)

Comment: I forgot to mention. After you change the login manager, reboot so that it has a chance to try to load.

Comment: (and hope for the best =P)

Comment: you could also run an apt-get fluxbox, and use fluxbox from that white terminal
(all paliative measures, for sure ...)

Comment: I did reboot every time...

Comment: I have a wrast error (libGL )

Comment: I just installed gnome-shell trhough `sudo apt-get install gnome-shell`, then I rebooted and login with gnoem classic (no effects), and I get the desktop and the bar fine. So the problem seems to be just caused to the shell.

Comment: sorry, I am not familiar with gnome shell. Does the previous comment mean "gnome shell worked fine" ?

Comment: no, the "no effect" version works, but not the full version. And unity doesn't work either.